# HttpHandler not rewriting

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing a simple HttpHandler for URL rewriting, but I'm hitting a brick wall.

I have created a HttpHandler class that's really simple just to test things:

```
public class HttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.RewritePath("default.aspx", false);
        //Rewriter.Rewrite(context);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I then have the following verb in the web.config:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*" type="Tizma.CMS.Runtime.HttpHandler"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

I basically want all incoming URL's to go through this rewritter. When I run this, ProcessRequest fires, but the RewritePath never gets to default.aspx.

Please bare in mind this is just a test and eventually default.aspx will be passed a query string along the lines of ?pageid=2 I just wanted to figure out how httphandlers worked first.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Andy - you can't call RewritePath() in a handler - it's way to late for that at that time. By the time you hit your handler the request has already routed to completion and RewritePath() doesn't do anything.

RewritePath must be called very early in the request cycle (like BeginRequest or anything before the CacheModule kicks in) to be effective so you most likely need an HttpModule and hook the appropriate early pipeline event.

Comment: I see, that's makes sense now. So the handler has to basically generate the content and pipe it out. OK, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help Rick, I'm sorted now.

Answer (score 2):

By using a HttpHandler, you're overriding the whole Web Forms mechanism for handling requests (`System.Web.UI.Page` implements `IHttpHandler`).  In your machine-level web.config file, you'll find

```
<add path="*.aspx" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" validate="true"/>
```

Rewriting the URL to `default.aspx` won't achieve much, because your web.config overrides that default handler mapping and says that your HttpHandler should be called to handle all URLs, including `default.aspx`.

You want a HttpModule, most likely handling the `BeginRequest` event. A HttpModule can handle individual events through the request lifecycle without overriding all of the standard behaviour.

Comment: Thanks Steve. That's exactly what I'm doing now. I've hooked into the BeginRequest event on my own custom HttpModule. Works a treat :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try "http://urlrewriter.net/". It has what you require as an out of the box solution.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect to see?  RewritePath changes the path internally without showing a different URL to the user.  If default.aspx is called, then it's working.

Comment: That's correct. I don't want the users url to change, but internally I want to open my default.aspx page with a query string of ?pageno=3

Default.aspx then renders the right page details. My issue is that default.aspx never seems to get to its Page_Load event.